# Am I using methods, constructors & getters right?

Tags: java, constructor, getter

I have a class that calculates the mean of an ArrayList, and I'm wondering whether I have it set up correctly? I am still very new to Java, so what I want to end up with is just to take an ArrayList as a parameter, and return it within the main method using:

```
StatCalc stats = new StatCalc(someArrayList);
System.out.printf("Mean of someArrayList is: %.3f\n", stats.getAverage());
```

Here is the StatCalc class

```
public class StatCalc {
    //declare inst variables & method
    private double average = 0;
    private double meanCalc(ArrayList<Double> myList) {
        double sum = 0;
        if (!myList.isEmpty()) {
            for (Double element : myList) {
                sum += element;
            }
        }
        return sum / myList.size();
    }
    //Constructor
    public StatCalc(ArrayList<Double> myList) {
        double average = meanCalc(myList);
        this.average = average;

    }

    //getter
    public double getAverage() {
         return average;
    }
}
```

I am just wondering is this is how it's 'supposed' to be done in Java, as before I had the meanCalc method inside the constructor, which worked but I thought was bad practice?

Comment: This looks OK- except the stuff happening in the constructor is probably not what you want.  You should create a `setter` function to set the average.  Currently, `average` is not being set on the field `average` because you're assigning it to a local `double` instead.

Comment: it depends how you would want to use the class. But it rather looks like you should create a static method that accepts a list and calculates the average from it, instead of creating an instance of the object each time you would want to get the average of a list.

Comment: you could implement caching : initialize the average at null in the constructor, then when getAverage() is called check the average field against null ; if it is null, compute it and store it in the average field, then in any case return the average field. This way it will only be computed once, but it will be done outside of the constructor.

Comment: You should not use the implementation type as an input parameter to your method. Instead of:
private double meanCalc(ArrayList<Double> myList) {
Use:
 private double meanCalc(List<Double> myList) {

Answer (score 2):

In your constructor, you are declaring `average` as constructor-scoped.

Just remove `double` from: `double average = meanCalc(myList);`

That will assign your instance field, instead of a variable with the same name inside your constructor.

In turn, the `getAverage()` method will return instance field `average` after it's been assigned, instead of its default value as unassigned, which is `0.0`.

In short:

```
//Constructor
public StatCalc(ArrayList<Double> myList) {
    average = meanCalc(myList);
}
```

**Final note**

If you are delivering a functionality that only depends on the parameters given, you can probably do without creating an instance of your class.

You could simply have a static method returning `double` and taking a `List<Double>` as parameter.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect :) Could you expand on your final note? If it's helpful, here's the plan: There is also another method in this class that calculates standard deviation of this list. The idea is then to make another class which iterates over the array and uses the mean and std in this calculation, so really I don't actually need to print out these results.

Comment: @TomKeyte what you want to do is have a single utility class with only `static` methods that take the arguments and return the results. So, no instance fields, no constructors, no instance methods. Optionally, you can also use asynchronous calculations if you think the data crunched will be big. But that's ways too broad for this question. I'd suggest you start by refactoring your class, removing the constructor/instance fields/methods, and make your `statCalc` method `static`, then take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, under java 8+, all your code can be replaced by only one line :

```
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
    [...]
OptionalDouble average = list.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).average();
```